# Shell command From PHP Is Being Executed Partially Only

Tags: php, git, shell

I have created a makefile as below:

```
.PHONY: all update-repo dependency-install unit-tests file-permission

    all: update-repo dependency-install unit-tests file-permission

    update-repo:
        git reset --hard
        git pull origin master

    dependency-install:
        composer update

    unit-tests:
        vendor/bin/phpunit

    file-permission:
        chmod 777 application/logs
        chmod 777 application/cache
        chmod 777 application/models/proxies
```

Now trying to execute it from php with following script:

```
echo shell_exec("make");
```

Not that both files are given 777 permission.

Now I am trying to execute those make commands by executing the php script from web url. After executing start, I only get following output:

```
git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 758a275 test commit
git pull origin master
```

So, for some reason other commands aren't being executed. Does anyone have any clue why? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to do, **chmod 777 is always wrong** and a serious security problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permissions issue. Make sure the errors are also going to stdout to find out what is going wrong:

```
echo shell_exec("make 2>&1");
```

More info: [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21)

Comment: Thanks, yes, it was a permission issue.